# Is it possible to do software emulation without Xilinx FPGA and run the code on CPU?

Tags: xilinx, vivado-hls

I am kind of new to FPGA's and I need to write some code for Xilinx Alveo U280 FPGA. I wonder if there is a way to make software emulation without FPGA on CPU?

Comment: Yes it is possible, with the qemu flow: https://docs.xilinx.com/r/en-US/ug1393-vitis-application-acceleration/QEMU

Answer (score 0):

You can make software using on the FPGA processor. Firstly you should create block diagram.(Microblaze, Axi GPIO...) and you can make software on SDK or Vitis platform with C language.